# How to dynamically get the dynamically created ID in a li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to learn js (and a tad of jquery) and I have run into two difficulties when trying to  find a way to combine solutions that I find.

Just a little warning that this code is a mix of a few tutorials that I have recently done.  I am very new to js.

So I start with a basic html with a few li.

```
<body>  
<ol id="liste">
<li class="active">   
</li>
<li>      
</li>
<li>
</li>   
</ol>
<div id="main_ima">



</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want to create ids for each "li" so in my main.js I add this:

```
var idVar = $("#liste").find("li").each(function(index){
$(this).attr("id","num-li-"+index);
});
```

This works great so far. Everytime I add a new li, it gets a new id. I also put it into a var because I will need to use it later.

In th console, If I type idVar, it gives me the whole list of li.  If I type idVar[3].  it only gives me the li associated to the [3].  Perfect.

Now I want to get something to appear when one of the li is clicked.  For example, I will use the [3]. So I add this to my main.js

```
var imaContainer = document.getElementById('main_ima')
var listed = document.getElementById('liste');



idVar[3].addEventListener("click", appar); 


function appar(){

$(idVar[3]).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");



var imaSel = new XMLHttpRequest();

imaSel.open('GET', 'https://domain.link.to.file.json');
imaSel.onload = function() {

var imaLo = JSON.parse(imaSel.responseText);
renderHTML(imaLo); 
};
imaSel.send();


};


function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlS = "";

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                           htmlS += "<p>" + data[i].name + " is a " + data[i].species + ".</p>";                           

}                              


imaContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlS);

}
```

Just a side note, I added the add/remove "active" class for CSS.

So when I click the li[3], it works almost as expected.  The only thing is when I reclick [3] it produces the result a 2nd time.  And again, if I click it a 3rd time, it produces the result a 3rd time, without remove the past results. (which is not totally what I want.  Just the 1st result would be better.)

But that is not the main problem I am facing.

I would like the [number] to be dynamically detected, based on the id of the clicked li.  I could, in a very ugly way, copy and past this code for every [number] I have.   and it would work.  But then, what if I want to add more li elements, I would need to add more copy and paste of the above code, giving me possibly huge files for nothing.  This is surely not the best way, although it would work.

I'm sure this can be done dynamically.. but that is mostly why I am here. :)

Afterwards, once the dynamic has been added to the clicked li, I would also like the link to be changed dynamically based on the li id.  For example, instead of :

```
imaSel.open('GET', 'https://domain.link.to.file.json');
```

something like:

```
imaSel.open('GET', "https://domain.link.to.file" + var +".json");
```

the var being equal to the [3] number of the clicked li.

In this case, when I try to add a var with a for loop, I always get the "var = max.length" instead of the "var = [id of clicked item]".

So there you have it.  Do you need more details?

This is my first JS and/or Jquery try.  I've been playing with it for a few days but when I search for answers,  when I implement the "solutions" it alwas gives me some new problem.  So I am showing you the code that is the closest, IMO, to what I am looking for.

Hopefully, I am not too far away of somehting that works and is not as big as my solutions. :)

Thanks for your time and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you are trying to do. But inside the event handler, `this` refers to the clicked element. Maybe that's all you need. I don't understand why you need the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- You don't need to assign `id` attributes to your `li`. You actually never need that `id`. This will work just as well (note also the `>` in the selector which makes the `find` call unnecessary):

  ```
  var $li = $("#liste > li");
  ```

  Already now you can address each of the `li` as `$li[3]`, although that is not the "best practise". Better is `$li.get(3)`. I also like the convention to start the variable with `$` when it is the result of a jQuery selection. It gives a clue that you can apply jQuery methods to it.
- You don't need to assign a click handler to each `li` separately. With jQuery `on` (instead of the native `addEventListener`) you can assign one event handler for all of them at once.

  ```
  $li.on('click', apar)
  ```
- The callback you define for `on` will have `this` set to the particular `li` element that has been clicked, so you can do:

  ```
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  ```

  ... without any array lookup.
- jQuery offers easy functions for several types of HTTP requests, so you don't need to use `XMLHttpRequest`. In fact, there is one specifically for getting JSON, so you don't even have to parse the response:

  ```
  $.getJSON('https://domain.link.to.file.json', renderHTML);
  ```
- The jQuery `index()` method can give you the sequence number of that `li`:

  ```
  $.getJSON('https://domain.link.to.file' + $(this).index() + '.json', renderHTML);
  ```
- To replace the inner HTML of a certain element, the jQuery `html` method can be used:

  ```
  $('#main_ima').html(htmlS);
  ```

  Note also how you don't need the DOM native `getElementById` method, jQuery can look that up for you with the short `$('#main_ima')`.

#### Example

Here is a working example with a fake JSON serving server:

```js
$("#liste > li").on('click', apar);

function apar() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' 
              + (1+$(this).index()), renderHTML);
}

function renderHTML(data) {
    // This particular JSON request returns an object with body property
    var htmlS = data.body; 
    $('#main_ima').html(htmlS);
}

// On page load, click on the first `li` to automatically load the data for it 
$('#liste > li:first').click();
```

```css
#liste { width: 40px }
.active { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="liste">
    <li class="active">load 1</li>
    <li>load 2</li>
    <li>load 3</li>   
</ol>
<div id="main_ima"></div>
```

Comment: Just a follow-up question, if I may :)       I have added a new div and would like to add an image from a file which has the name of the clicked li number.     `$('#main_pic').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="https://www.domain/folder/pictures/0.jpg" />');`      it works but if i re-click, a 2nd image appears.  also, if I try to `$('#main_pic').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="https://www.domain/folder/pictures/" + (1+$(this).index()) + ".jpg" />');`      It gives me error 403, forbiden because the 2nd part of the line   `+ (1+$(this).index()) + ".jpg" />');`      is ignored. @trincot   Ideas? thx

Comment: Sure, but that is more than one follow-up question, and the the comments section is really not suitable to treat them. Before prepending you should check with  `prev` method whether there already is an image, and if so don't prepend another. With the `+ (1+$this).....` part you used the wrong quotes. You need to stop the single quoted string, not the double quoted one. If you have more questions , please use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: True and good idea.  I have created a new question. @trincot if ever you want to have a look, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864867/adding-an-image-which-is-related-to-a-click-li  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The following answers your main concern, how to dynamically get the ID with jquery:

```js
$('.listen-to-me').click(function() { //Add event listener to class
  var elementId = $(this).attr('id'); //Get the 'id' attribute of the element clicked
  var idNumber = elementId.substring(elementId.indexOf("-") +1); //Get the index of the "-" in the string, and then cut everything prior
  alert(idNumber); //The final result
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="test-1" class="listen-to-me">1</li>
  <li id="test-2" class="listen-to-me">2</li>
  <li id="test-3" class="listen-to-me">3</li>
  <li id="test-4" class="listen-to-me">4</li>
  <li id="test-5" class="listen-to-me">5</li>
</ul>
```