# Dynamically adding an image which is related to a clicked li

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow-up of my last question. If you like, you can find previous details here: [How to dynamically get the dynamically created ID in a li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803627/how-to-dynamically-get-the-dynamically-created-id-in-a-li)

I have added a `<div>` for a picture.  I called it `<div class="main_pic">`

Here is the code I currently have:

HTML:

```
<body>
<ol id="liste">
<li class="active"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>   
</ol>
<div id="main_ima"></div>
<div id="main_pic"></div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have tried to prepend an image with something like this:

```
$('#main_pic').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="https://domain/folders/to/pictures/" + (1+$(this).index()) + ".jpg" />');
```

or

```
$('#main_pic').prepend("<img id='theImg' src='https://domain/folders/to/pictures/' + (1+$(this).index()) + '.jpg' />");
```

or

```
$('#main_pic').prepend("<img id='theImg' src='https://domain/folders/to/pictures/0.jpg' />");
```

In the comments of the previous question, I stated that I have added a new div and would like to add an image from a file which is related to the clicked li.

But these tries (amoung many others) have created problems.  The first and 2nd one give me a 403, because the 2nd part after the  `+ (1+$(this).index()) +` is not seen and the 3rd try is not dynamic and also, when I reclick on the li, it gives me a 2nd picture without removing the first.

In the previous question, in te commentairy: trincot suggested to check with `prev` method whether there already is an image, but I have failed to incoporate this in my main.js file.  Maybe because I can't figure out the `+ (1+$(this).index()) +` part?

Here is what it currently looks like:

main.js

```
$("#liste > li").on('click', apar);

function apar() {
$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + (1+$(this).index()), renderHTML);

$('#main_pic').prepend("<img id='theImg' src='https://domain/folders/to/pictures/' + (1+$(this).index()) + '.jpg' />");


$(document).ready(function(){
// Do something with the DOM
$('.active').click(function(){
$('.main_pic').attr('class', $(this.id)); 
});
});
```

I think I could solve this with CSS with something like

```
.main_pic_1 {
background-image: url("https://domain/folders/to/pictures/0.jpg");   
}
.main_pic_2 {
background-image: url("https://domain/folders/to/pictures/1.jpg");   
}
```

etc.

and adding a class with js related to a clicked li id.  But that doesn't seem like the best way to do this and would create lots of code lines in the CSS.

Any ideas?

Thanks!  any help is very appreciated.

EDIT: the new link that works is `$('#main_pic').prepend("<img id='theImg' src='https://domain/folders/to/pictures/" + (1+$(this).index()) + ".jpg' />");`  but this still gives me multiple pictures on each click.  (the pictures stay on the page and one additionnal picture is added on each click.) it is however, the correct picture that is being added.

Solution:
`$('#main_pic').html("<img id='theImg' src='https://domain/folders/to/pictures/" + (1+$(this).index()) + ".jpg' />");`

Comment: Open your browser dev tool and use `console.log("mystring" + number + ".jpg")` etc at strategic places in your code to figure out what happens, otherwise it's just endless trial and error...

Comment: great suggestion!  I have figure out the correct link.  Now, I need to figure out how to only get 1 image, possibly with 'prev' . @yezzz

Comment: `.append()` instead of `prepend`? I assume you're trying to put the image into #main_pic

Comment: both `append` and `prepend` put it inside the element... http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: I figure you ever only want 1 picture inside the main-pic... so use `.html()` instead of append/prepend

Comment: You are correct. thanks @yezzz .   It is now working as expected.